# Eliminate hours, minutes and seconds from a date in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm trying to remove the hours, minutes and seconds from a date using the following code :

```
TRUNC(column_date, 'YY')
```

But I get this : `01JAN2008:00:00:00`, while I want this : `01JAN2008`.

What should I do?

Comment: If its Oracle why add the MySQL tag?? Please dont spam tags

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNC()` works as expected, and returns the original date truncated to year, as a *date datatype*. You want to format this date before displaying it (this actually means converting it to a string). For this, you can use the `TO_CHAR()` function.

You probably want:

```
 TO_CHAR(TRUNC(column_date, 'YY'), 'ddmonyyyy')
```

Please note that this expression could be simplified to avoid the use of `TRUNC()`, as follows:

```
 '01JAN' || TO_CHAR(column_date, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: No need for TRUNC anymore :-)

Comment: @dnoeth : yep, absolutely... I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `to_char`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129

Try using it in this way:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(column_date, 'DD/MON/YYYY')
FROM x;
```

Where x is the table you are trying to query.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to use

```
select to_char(column_date,'ddMONyyyy') FROM yourTable
```

Even you can invoke with

```
select to_char(column_date,'ddMONyyyy','nls_date_language=english') FROM yourTable
```

to guarantee to see the abbreviation `JAN` in the case your `session`/`system` date language value is different than `english`

to display as expected.